# Accelerometer stop animation Movement query

Tags: c#, animation, accelerometer, unity-game-engine

I have a script named `AccelerometerMovement` which is taking care of accelerometer controls of player. The player is just moving **left** and **right** so I am just taking `Input.acceleration.x` component.

The script is as follows:

```
public class AccelerometerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool isandroid;

    private float AccelerometerStoreValue;

    private robotController theRobo;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        theRobo = FindObjectOfType<robotController> ();


        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        isandroid=true;
        #else
        isandroid=false;
        #endif
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (isandroid) {
            //android specific code
            Accelerometer();


        } else {
            //any other platform specific code

        }
    }

    void Accelerometer(){
        AccelerometerStoreValue = Input.acceleration.x;
        if (AccelerometerStoreValue > 0.1f) {
            //right
            theRobo.moveRight();

        } else if (AccelerometerStoreValue < -0.1f) {
            //left
            theRobo.moveLeft();

        }
    }
}
```

As u can see above according to left and right..it is calling *moveLeft()* and *moveRight()* from another script which is the actual player controller script.

The other script where the actual function is :

```
// after Update()
public void jump(){
        if (grounded) {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (myRigidBody.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
            doubleJump = false;

        }

        if(!doubleJump&&!grounded){

            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (myRigidBody.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
            doubleJump = true;
        }
    }

    public void moveLeft(){



        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (-moveSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
        robotMove = true;
        lastMove = myRigidBody.velocity.x;
        anim.SetFloat ("MoveX", -moveSpeed);
        anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", lastMove);
        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);


    }

    public void moveRight(){



        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (moveSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
        robotMove = true;
        lastMove = myRigidBody.velocity.x;
        anim.SetFloat ("MoveX", moveSpeed);
        anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", lastMove);
        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);



    }
    public void stop(){

        robotMove = false;

        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);

    }
```

Now when I checked the controls on actual device the controls are working fine but there is one problem!

The problem is that when player starts moving the animation of movement starts but when it stops the **idle animation (or stop animation) doesn't start** and even when still the **player movement animation keeps on going.**

Now I am not able to understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: This is C# not Unityscript. Please understand this. You will likely get more help if you get the tags right. You can google Unity C# vs Unityscript to see the difference.

Comment: Ok I have changed it ! But do u know the solution @Programmer ?

Comment: Not really but please edit your code and add which part of the code should stop and play the idle animations.

Comment: check your anims and/or sleeping bodies https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html

Comment: I solved it ..putting answer

Answer (score 1):

the `Stop()` function above is lying dormant. We need to call it by putting one extra condition :

```
 else if (AccelerometerStoreValue > 0.01f && AccelerometerStoreValue < 0.09f || AccelerometerStoreValue < -0.01f && AccelerometerStoreValue > -0.09f) {
            theRobo.stop ();
        }
```

the values will take care of device still and will set the idle animations to work ! Put above code just after 2nd **else if** in `Accelerometer()` function .